# OS upgrade ignoring that packages have been set to hold by apt-mark

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

My understanding of how this should work:

I set packages to hold with `apt-mark hold <PACKAGE>` and that should mean they get ignored as part of `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

Meaning they should also be ignored as part of `do-release-upgrade`.

Upgrading from 18.04 -> 20.04 I noticed this worked for packets like `corosync` and `pacemaker`.

I set them to `hold` and `do-release-upgrade`  didn't complain and left them alone. `corosync` 2.4.3 was not upgraded to 3.0

However, on a different server I set `zookeeper` to be held back, and `do-release-upgrade` won't move past it. It keeps complaining I need to upgrade everything.

Where does this difference come from? All mentioned packets come from the main ubuntu apt repositories, so I can't just disable a file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to achieve this.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The "difference" is simply that only some package version requirements change across releases (zookeeper). Others don't (corosync). If 22.04 requires a higher version of zookeeper than you are comfortable with, then stay on 20.04. DON'T try to game apt or force apt to release-upgrade without all the required package versions. That's called a "partial upgrade" and it always ends in tears.